# Populating a combo box with an array

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I am new to Java and I am populating a combo box. I used this line of code:

```
    String[] val = new String[100];
    for (int j = 0; j<val.length; j++)
    {
        CmbSize.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(val));
    }
```

However this doesn't seem to work. The combo box gives a 100 empty space with nothing in them.  Can anyone help me please?

Comment: Well you're not populating your array, to start with... it's just 100 null elements. What did you expect to be in there? And why are you setting the model 100 times?

Comment: 1)  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  2) Don't add a tag for your IDE unless this question is *about* the IDE.  I added two more appropriate tag instead. 3) Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Comment: [For all reference types (§4.3), the default value is null](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.12.5).

Answer (score 4):

You have the right idea - but you are just creating a new empty model 100 times.

```
String[] val = new String[100];
CmbSize.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(val));
```

You have created an empty array with 100 elements in it, and you have added that to the model without needing a loop.

What you do need a loop for though is to fill val with values of some sort.

```
String[] val = new String[100];

for (int j = 0; j<val.length; j++) {
   val[j] = String.valueOf(j);
}

CmbSize.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(val));
```

This will just fill each entry with a number but it will get you started.